# Discord.js how to ping Members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ping

I wanted the bot to ping a member ( with @) and i tried

```
message.channel.send(<@id>+" text")
```

but it says `unexpected sign '<'.`
How can i make the bot ping members?

Comment: `<@id>` is obviously not a valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

member ping: `<@${memberID}>`

Channel ping: `<#${channelID}>`

Role ping: `<@&${roleID}>`

Also you need to use [`] like:

```js
message.channel.send({content: `<@${memberID}> i pinged you`})
```